# Symbols defined with defsym give incorrect address on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linker

If I define a symbol address when linking a program on Ubuntu 16.10, this doesn't seem to produce the correct address when running the program. For example taking the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int mem_;

int main()
{
  printf("%p\n", &mem_);
}
```

and compiling with

```
gcc example.c -o example -Xlinker --defsym=mem_=0x80
```

then running the program prints 0x80 on older Ubuntu systems, but a random number on Ubuntu 16.10. The 0x80 symbol seems to go into the executable, as shown by the nm program, however.

Any ideas what's causing this? I'm suspecting a security feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the GCC section of the ChangeLog (found here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/YakketyYak/ReleaseNotes)

"We have modified GCC to by-default compile programs with position independent executable support, on the amd64 and ppc64el architectures, to improve the security benefits provided by Address Space Layout Randomization."

To disable this option, simply add -no-pie to GCC's flags.

Comment: Thanks - I did try --no-pie, but this compiles with an error!

Comment: It's actually -no-pie not --no-pie (single dash). Assuming you tried that, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Sorry - my previous comment was badly written. I previously had tried --no-pie (with an error), but -no-pie does work. THanks for the help.